# How can i Pause the slick marque slider on hover and move ltr and rtl on of of each sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I want to pause the slider on hover and also want to move slick marque slider from left to right on hover to left and vice versa also.

Answer (score 0):

This Code might be helpful..... Use `rtl: true` slick option to reverse slider but slider must have `dir="rtl"` attribute

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var $imageSlider = $('.image-slider');
 $imageSlider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 15,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
    useCSS: false,
  speed: 1000,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
  pauseOnFocus: false,
  pauseOnHover: true,
 });
  $imageSlider.mouseenter(function(event){
    if($imageSlider.attr('dir') == 'rtl'){
      $imageSlider.removeAttr('dir');
      $imageSlider.slick('slickSetOption', {rtl: false});
    }
    else{
      $imageSlider.attr('dir', 'rtl');
      $imageSlider.slick('slickSetOption', {rtl: true});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;    
}
.slider-wrap{
 position: relative;
}
.image-slider{
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrap{
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrap:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0.3;
 z-index: 1;
}
.img-wrap img{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: auto;
 height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.0/slick.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrap">
 <div class="image-slider">
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439748.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/13219.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439753.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439748.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/13219.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439753.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439748.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/13219.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439753.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439748.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/13219.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439753.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439748.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/13219.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439753.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439748.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/13219.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/439753.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```